How to proper instantiate TypeVar typing declaration with a bound variable?
The problem I am facing is when I am attempting to use SQLAlchelmy ORM declaractions to write my session queries and utilizing VSCode's recognition of class types to auto complete my coded queries.
Based on my understanding, I have coded an TypeVar declaration in the following format:
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from typing import TypeVar

def generate_schema(prefix: str):
    class SchemaA:
        tablename: str = f"{prefix}_table"
        attr1: int = len(prefix)
    return SchemaA

SchemaA = generate_schema("raw")
SchemaAType = TypeVar("SchemaAType", bound=SchemaA)

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("xxx")
Session = sessionmaker(engine)

with Session() as sess:
    table_a: SchemaAType = sess.query(SchemaA).where(SchemaA.attr1 == 3).first()

prefix_perc: float = table_a.attr1 / len(table_a.tablename)

It used to be able to work properly and VSCode will also be able to map the internal attributes of SchemaA (as it is a class object) successfully but recently, table_a: SchemaAType is throwing a linting error: "Variable not allowed in type expression".
Furthermore, table_a is also no longer recognized with the internal attributes of SchemaA variable.
What is it that I am doing wrong now? I cannot seem to find an answer online for this formatting error despite it not throwing any error during runtime.
I have tried researching on using other Var types instead such as NewType but based on documentation, those are not for binding variables to Typing.
Ideally, I would like to avoid defining a generic class for SchemaA so I can centralize the definition of SchemaA in one function.
My current python specifications are:
python 3.10.6
typing-extensions==4.9.0

First, a TypeVar is meaningless outside of generic classes, functions and type aliases; vara_info: ClassAType = execute_var() is thus invalid. Second, you are creating a new class everytime, with the only common base class being type/object; you can't statically refer to such a dynamically created class. This seems to be an XY problem. What is the original problem you are trying to solve?

What, exactly, "worked properly"? The code you show is full of undefined names. Provide a [mcve] of something that you claim used to work

@chepner Thanks for the feedback. As the original problem is closely tied to using the ORM class of sqlalchemy, I oversimplified my code and mistakenly thought that was sufficient. I have made the above changes (only part will not run will be the engine connection string) - would this suffice?

@InSync I see, I was hoping that somehow it is possible to refer to a dynamically created class as typing... I guess the only way is to define a static class of the same attributes separately for typing reference?
The original problem I am trying to solve is to effectively use sqlalchemy's ORM constructs to make query construction easier.
